# Explanation of shortcuts in C

Tags: c

Can someone explain what exactly is happening in these two statements listed below:

```
1) int enabled = val == 0; //val is an int

2) int sync = param || (foo->delay == NULL); //param and delay is both int
```

Comment: Old C had no boolean type, so all boolean arithmetic was done with `int`. Is that what's putting you off?

Comment: i doubt `foo->delay` is int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int enabled = val == 0;
```

read as

```
int enabled = (val == 0);
```

and

```
(val == 0)
```

will be either 0 or non zero if val is 0 or not. `enabled` will then be initialized with that value

Equivalent to:

```
int enabled;
if(val == 0)
{
    enabled = 1;
}
else
{
    enabled = 0;
}
```

now you do that same analysis on the second one

Answer (score 4):

You will set the variable `enabled` to `1` if `val` is equal to `0` and `0` otherwise.

`sync` will be equal to `1` if `param` is non-zero and in case it is `0` then it will be `1` if `foo->delay` is `NULL` else it will be `0`.

From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9p3)  §6.5.9p3 backing up what I said:

> The `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational operators except for their lower precedence.108) *Each of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type int.* For any pair of operands, exactly one of the relations is true.

Also in case `||` there is standard saying the evaluation logic: from  §6.5.14

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the `||` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second operands. *If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.*

Also in the same section the rule which dictates what will be the result if `param` is non-zero.

> The `||` operator shall yield `1` if either of its operands compare unequal to `0`; otherwise, it yields `0`. The result has type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

C only adopted a true boolean type from C++ with C99, though it named it `_Bool` so it wouldn't conflict with pre-existing code and provided the header `<stdbool.h>` to make it nicer.
The prior convention that only `0` is considered falsey (a literal zero, which in a pointer-context is a null-pointer), and anything else truthy was not changed. (That's the reverse to how command shells do it by the way.)

All boolean operators and conversion from `_Bool` use canonical values of `0` and `1`.

That should be enough history and details to understand the code.